# Dividing by previous row in pandas with condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a new column which is division of previous of row. But some of the rows have 0 value. So my conditionl statement is: If the division between 2 rows is infinity or nan, the value in Growth rate column will be 0. Else, it will be division with the previous row.

'''
n=len(df)
for j in range(0,n-1):

```
if ((df.iloc[j,4]/df.iloc[j-1,4]) == inf):
    df['GrowthRate']=0
else:
    df['GrowthRate'] = df.iloc[j,4]/df.iloc[j-1,4]
    j=j+1
```

'''

The output is all my values in the column are inf.

Comment: `df['GrowthRate'] = df.iloc[:, 4].div(df.iloc[:, 4].shift(), axis=0).replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0).fillna(0)` ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to deal with `NaN` and `Inf`:

```
import numpy as np

df['GrowthRate'] = (df.iloc[:, 4].div(df.iloc[:, 4].shift())
                    .fillna(0).replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0))
```

---

**Example**

```
np.random.seed(2020)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-3, 4, (10, 5)))
print(df)

#    0  1  2  3  4
# 0 -3 -3  0  3  0
# 1  0  2  0 -3  2
# 2 -3 -3 -3 -1 -2
# 3  0  0 -1  3  0
# 4  3  2 -3  1  1
# 5 -3  3  1 -2 -2
# 6  2 -1 -2  3  2
# 7  2 -1  3  3  3
# 8  2  1  3  3  1
# 9 -1  0  1 -2  1

df['GrowthRate'] = (df.iloc[:, 4].div(df.iloc[:, 4].shift())
                    .fillna(0).replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0))
```

[out]

```
   0  1  2  3  4  GrowthRate
0 -3 -3  0  3  0    0.000000
1  0  2  0 -3  2    0.000000
2 -3 -3 -3 -1 -2   -1.000000
3  0  0 -1  3  0   -0.000000
4  3  2 -3  1  1    0.000000
5 -3  3  1 -2 -2   -2.000000
6  2 -1 -2  3  2   -1.000000
7  2 -1  3  3  3    1.500000
8  2  1  3  3  1    0.333333
9 -1  0  1 -2  1    1.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

if the value above is 0 then divide by `np.inf`, resulting in 0, else divide by previous value

```
col = df.iloc[:,4]
df['GrowthRate'] = col.div(col.where(col.eq(0), np.inf))
```

If you need fill `NaN` at the end:

```
df['GrowthRate'] = col.div(col.where(col.eq(0), np.inf)).fillna(0)
```

Comment: I'm getting all `0`'s when I try this?